# What if you call the recursive function before instructions?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int i = 1;

void myFunction(int counter) {

    if (counter == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        myFunction(--counter);
        cout << i << " : " << counter << endl;
        i++;
        return;
    }
}
```

I ran the program with

```
myFunction(4)
```

This code shows the following in console:

```
1 : 0
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 3
```

It doesn't make sense to me how recursion is working here. If the call to the function is done after instructions then its perfectly clear to me, but not before!

I'm mostly baffled as to why the program is counting upwards here. If anybody can explain to me the mechanics of this program, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: What was passed into the function? What is the value of counter?

Comment: myFunction(4) .. I'll add that in, sorry.

Comment: @DavidV, why not put some `cout` statements and trace how it works?

Comment: A pen and a piece of paper would help you understand this. Else use  a debugger/profiler.

Comment: What do you think would happen if you had separate functions: `void myFunction0() {}` `void myFunction1() {myFunction0(); cout << i << " : " << 1 << endl; i++;}` `void myFunction2() {myFunction1(); cout << i << " : " << 2 << endl; i++;}` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
int main() {
    myFunction(4);
}
```

what happens is the following:

```
myFunction(3); // with cout << i << ": " << 3 << endl; i++; waiting in the queue
myFunction(2); // with cout << i << ": " << 2 << endl; i++; waiting in the queue
myFunction(1); // with cout << i << ": " << 1 << endl; i++; waiting in the queue
myFunction(0); // with cout << i << ": " << 0 << endl; i++; waiting in the queue
```

Since `cout << i << " : " << 0 << endl; i++;` is the last one in the queue, it will be first executed, which prints

```
1: 0
```

After this, `i` increases by 1 and becomes 2, and `cout << i << " : " << 1 << endl; i++;` prints

```
2: 1
```

and `i` becomes 3,

```
...
```

and so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was suspecting it had something to do with some type of queue. Under what title can I search for more about "the queue" (relating to recursive functions)?

Comment: @DavidV The word "queue" in my answer is used in the "everyday sense", just like a queue in front of a busy restaurant.  It is just how a function call works: when calling a function, the "system" goes into that function, does something in that function, exits that function and continues with what are left over.  I am not sure specifically what to look for, but maybe you can check these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c

Comment: In your example, maybe we could imagine a procrastinating person, who is doing something, and distracted by the second thing, and while doing the second thing, distracted by the third, ..., and so on; after finishing the last thing, the person continues with the thing before the last thing, and so on, and finally finishes the first thing.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest simplifying the code a little to understand what's going on:

```
void myFunction(int counter) {
    cout << "Started function with " << counter << "." << endl;
    if(counter == 0) {
        cout << "Found a 0, returning." << endl;
        return;
    } else {
        cout << "Before recursive call." << endl;
        myFunction(--counter);
        cout << "After recursive call." << endl;
    }
}

myFunction(1);
```

You should see this output:

```
Started function with 1.
Before recursive call.
Started function with 0.
Found a 0, returning.
After recursive call.
```

If that makes sense to you, try increasing the number you initially pass in, and you should be able to piece together what's going on in your original code.

Comment: [Indeed that makes it crystal clear!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeFBCWHF3aUxRZUE)

Comment: You might consider printing `counter` in front of `"Before recursive call."`

Comment: So is there something like a waiting line here? How does the computer know that once 0 was returned, then calls that happened before can now execute lines that come next to the recursion?

Comment: @DavidV Same way it know that for **any** function call - recursion isn't a special thing! E.g. when you write `printf("hello "); printf("world\n");`, how does the compiler know that once hello was printed, then it can execute the line that comes after `printf("hello ");`?

Comment: It seems different to me here... The compiler is executing instructions (after the base case) in the reverse order! I think its related to what another user said about "the queue" which I didnt know about.

Comment: It truly isn't different from any other function call. Make four identical functions called `myFunction1` through `myFunction4` and have them each call each other. Then there's no recursion, but the exact same thing will happen. (The functions should be identical except which other function they call.)

Comment: @DavidV The compiler is not executing instructions in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the program with:
`myFunction(4)`
 The first thing that happens is this calls `myFunction(3)` which calls `myFunction(2)` and so on.

```
{
        myFunction(--counter); //Executed first
        //followed by this
        cout << i<< " : " << counter << endl;
        i++;
        return;
}
```

Therefore, `myFunction(4)` -> `myFunction(3)` ->`myFunction(2)` -> `myFunction(1)` -> cout statements of `myFunction(1)` -> cout statements of `myFunction(2)` -> cout statements of `myFunction(3)` -> cout statements of `myFunction(4)` 

`myFunction(0)` simply returns whereas `myFunction(1)` prints a statement `1 : 0`.
 Then the code for `myFunction(2)` is executed and so on producing an output:

```
1 : 0
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 3
```